# How to change text colours in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Want to make the "Create a desktop shortcut" text bolder or change the text color to red in Select Additional Tasks wizard page.

```
    [setup]
    UsePreviousTasks=no
    
    [Tasks]
    Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}";
    
    [Icons]
    Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "path"; 
    Name: "{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "path"; Tasks: desktopicon

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
WizardForm.TasksList.Font.Color := clRed;
end
```

[image]

I have tried this `WizardForm.TasksList.Color := clWhite;` `WizardForm.ReadyMemo.Color := clWhite`. It but it looks like below image since i , so is there any way to make the text `Create a desktop shortcut` red or bold ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  I tried added this `WizardForm.TasksList.Font.Color := clRed;` line to both `InitializeWizard` and `CurPageChanged` but no luck, it still looks like in the first image

Comment: For me it just turned the Additional shortcut to Red(added image above)

Comment: Probably because your checkbox is disabled, what overrides the color.

Comment: I have updated my code..if it is disabled then how ccna i enable it? i changed `UsePreviousTasks` yes.. sill same

Comment: I'm quite sure that Inno Setup never disables the checkboxes in the task list on its own. So I would suspect that you disable the checkbox yourself in your code. If you disagree, consider posting a separate question with [mcve].